# How to find statistics using stat() in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to display the stats() of a Double RDD

`val stat = x.map(s => s._2).stats()`

where x is of type RDD[Double]

In spark-shell, this run fine.

But while running it in eclipse and compiling using sbt, it throws the following error.

`value stats is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]`

Comment: Have you imported `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ ` ?

Comment: I should then repost this as an answer.

Comment: This is not completely "by the book" in one question, but which structure are you using to represent a date? Some tuple of three strings, as I see it?

Comment: I'm afraid you should open a new question with a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import additional functions for RDD's with doubles.

Add 'import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` to your source.

This is an usual "error" when something is missing for the RDD class.